# Android: how to use global variables, activities, onResume(), startActivityForResult and so on

Tags: android

I have some confusion in mind. Being new to android, I am writing an App which should:

1. check if bluetooth is available
2. if it is, enable it if turned off
3. scan for nearby devices and show them to the user
4. the user clicks (chooses) a device
5. the app, cyclically, pools the device and shows it status
6. while polling, the user can ask for more operations (other activities on the same device), then return to main screen

Passages from 1 to 4 are mandatory, but it seems difficult to lay them down in a straight (simple) manner: the main activity, which calls two intents (to enable BT and to scan devices) seems to interfere. It seems that the main activity's onCreate is called too often...

Question #1: should I do all the work in the onActivityResult() method? Or should that method be used to collect results, and the true work should be done in onResume()? I say so because while in step 5, when trying to launch other activities, android complains about "not having a context and you need to set the flag NEWTASK in the intent - "is that really what you want?")" (sorry, can't remember the exact message).

Moreover: the main screen shows some statuses from device, refreshed via postDelayed(), and also accepts button's clicks. When the user clicks a button and a new activity is created, what happens to the main activity? Does it lose its variables, context, or whatever? In that loop, I don't need anymore any result from the user clicked activities, so question #2 is should I use onResume? Or is onCreate() called again? If using onResume() I need to keep track of the app status, where to store that status? I am using a static global class, and it seem to work, but I've read that it is not a good idea.

I know this question is kind of a mess, but I've read google documentation and many questions here in SO, and found a mess. In this moment the app is more or less working, but it does strange things at times and, worse (question #3) by using it a few minutes it gets slower and slower - can it be it leaks memory, or it creates too many threads because of postDelayed()?

Comment: The question is too big to answer but all I can do is give you reference for this so you can carry on further. Follow this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_bluetooth) to understand the behavior of bluetooth and use the same via app. I hope this helps.

Comment: I thank you for your effort but, if you read my question, you notice that bluetooth is not the core problem; the problem is how to correctly lay out a (structured) app. I think, examples and tutorials are great, but too simple to learn something about complicated (structured) things. This is why I posted a question.

Comment: ...and, about your link... can you show me *where* the methods `void off(View v)` and `void on(View v)` are called? I can be wrong, but that example seems missing something.